How to handle react native dropdown picker in appium autoamation
everyone I am very new to mobile automation, and I am facing a problem Handling the drop-down picker because I am not able to inspect or scroll and am not able to find the locator. please help me out
I have tried send keys method but have not been able to get the solution, Please give me the exact solution.

Please take the [tour] and also read [ask]. You wrote (in your question): showing no such element exception If you are referring to NoSuchElementException class, then can you [edit] your question and post the entire error message and stack trace?
